# How to modify a mask to make it perfect circle

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have masks of imperfect circle like this one. How can I use opencv contour function (or any other way) to remove the artifacts in the top-right corner?

[image: circle]

Here is the data,:

```
mask = np.array([
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,255],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,255,255,255,255,255],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255],
[0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255],
[0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255],
[0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255],
[0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255],
[0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,255,255],
[0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Comment: Do you know the radius ahead of time?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help). Users are much more likely to help if you (1) show some research effort on your own (Google and StackOverflow searches), (2) learn what are appropriate questions for this forum and how to ask them, and (3) provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example to your specific problem.

Comment: @pciunkiewicz, the radius is not known

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An approach is to [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization) the image to obtain a binary image. From here, we perform [morphological opening](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#opening) with a [elliptical shaped kernel](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#structuring-element). This step will effectively remove the extra artifacts but will distort the circle a bit. To repair the circle, we find contours and use [`cv2.minEnclosingCircle()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minenclosingcircle#minenclosingcircle) then draw this onto a mask to get a perfect circle.

---

Here's the visualization of each step:

I took a screenshot of your image without the grid lines. Input image:

[image]

Otsu's threshold to obtain a binary image

[image]

Morph opening with elliptical shaped kernel

[image]

Result from `cv2.minEnclosingCircle()` and the resulting contour drawn onto a mask

[image]
[image]

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, convert to grayscale, then Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Morph open with a elliptical shaped kernel
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (75,75))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=4)

# Find contours and create perfect circle on mask
cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    ((x, y), r) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    cv2.circle(image, (int(x), int(y)), int(r), (36, 255, 12), 3)
    cv2.circle(mask, (int(x), int(y)), int(r), (255, 255, 255), -1)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey()
```

---

If you don't have an image and instead have a `np.array`, the process stays the same but you can skip the threshold step. Also depending on how large the image is, you may have to adjust the kernel size. For instance, changing it from `(75, 75)` to say `(10, 10)`. You could also experiment with the number of iterations to perform morph opening. Here's an example of how to do it if you had an `np.array` of points that formed the image

Input image `->` Morph open `->` Result

[image]
[image]
[image]

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

mask = np.array([ [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,255], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,255,255,255,255,255], [0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255], [0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255], [0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255], [0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255], [0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255], [0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255], [0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,255,255], [0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0], [0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0], [0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0], [0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]], dtype=np.uint8)

# Create blank image with the same size as mask
image = np.zeros(mask.shape, dtype=np.uint8)

# Morph open with a elliptical shaped kernel
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (10,10))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=2)

# Find contours and create perfect circle on mask
cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    ((x, y), r) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    cv2.circle(image, (int(x), int(y)), int(r), (255, 255, 255), -1)

cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: thanks for respone. My original image is the binary image itself. What will change in that case?

Comment: It shouldn't change. If its a binary image, you could load the image in as grayscale and skip the thresholding step

Comment: thanks again. For some reason, starting with binary image itself did not work.  `mask = np.array(<copied in the OP>)
thresh = mask.copy()
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (75,75))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=4)

# Find contours and create perfect circle on mask
cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    ((x, y), r) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    cv2.circle(mask, (int(x), int(y)), int(r), (255, 255, 255), -1)`

Comment: Oh you didn't mention that you had a `np.array` as input. It will affect the pipeline, I added an update. One thing to mention is that you may have to adjust the kernel size depending on the size of your image