# Segment photos of bio-samples to extract circular area of interest with Python image processing

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

I'm having issues with finishing the segmentation in some photos of bio-samples, I'm trying to analyze growth of bacteria with image processing, as in theory it should work. Here is one of the original images I have:

[image: biofilm of pseudomona]

I'm trying to segment the area inside the circle and see how the values of the pixels change as time passes. I've been trying a lot of techniques, as I'm relative new to analyzing these kind of samples.Initially I was using opencv, but I wasn't getting the results I wanted so now I'm using scikit-image for all the techniques for image processing and segmentation.
Here's the code I have until now:

```
from skimage import morphology, exposure, io, filters
from scipy import ndimage as ndi
from skimage.color import rgb2gray, label2rgb
from skimage.filters import sobel, rank
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y1=400
y2=1600
x1=700
x2=1900
test_img = io.imread(folders_path+hour_tested[0]+'5.jpg')
roi_test = test_img[y1:y2, x1:x2,:]
gray_img = rgb2gray(roi_test)
denoised_img = rank.median(gray_img, morphology.disk(5))
val = filters.threshold_otsu(denoised_img)
mask = denoised_img > val
elevation_map=sobel(denoised_img)
segmentation = morphology.watershed(elevation_map, mask=mask)
labeled_bio, num_seg = ndi.label(segmentation)
image_label_overlay = label2rgb(labeled_bio, image=gray_img)
plt.imshow(image_label_overlay)
plt.show()
```

On the last line I get to segment by different colors the areas of the sample and get the part I want to analyze in one label, is now that I don't know how to continue or at least how to just see that label and then create a mask.

I'm also sharing the labeled image for anyone to see and maybe help me in the next steps, I feel like or I'm really close to segment my area of interest or really far and confused.

Well here's the labeled image of the sample:

[image: segmented area with labels]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing the code this is the correct answer for the biofilm segmentation:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
def resize_image(image, percentage):
   scale_percent=percentage
   width = int(image.shape[1] * scale_percent/100)
   height= int(image.shape[0] * scale_percent/100)
   dimensions = (width, height)
   resized = cv2.resize(image, dimensions, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
   return resized
#this path is changed for each image in the DB
path=folders_path+hour_tested[0]+'1.jpg'
image = cv2.imread(path)
s_image = resize_image(image,50)
original = s_image.copy()
mask = np.zeros(s_image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(s_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
# Morph close
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7,7))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=3)
# Find contours and filter using contour area + contour approximation
# Determine perfect circle contour then draw onto blank mask
im,cnts,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04*peri, True)
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if len(approx) > 4 and (area > 8000 and area < 250000) and (peri<2000 and peri>1000):
        ((x, y), r) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        x,y,r = int(x),int(y),int(r)
        blank_circle=cv2.circle(mask, (x, y), r, (255, 255, 255), -1)
        filled_circle=cv2.circle(s_image, (x, y), r, (36, 255, 12), 3)
        # Extract ROI
        mask_ROI = blank_circle[y-r:y+r, x-r:x+r]
        mask_ROI = cv2.cvtColor(mask_ROI, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        image_ROI = filled_circle[y-r:y+r, x-r:x+r]
        result = cv2.bitwise_and(image_ROI, image_ROI, mask=mask_ROI)
        cv2.imwrite('result.png',result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using simple image processing techniques

- **Obtain binary image.** Load image, convert to grayscale, then Otsu's threshold to get a binary image
- **Perform morphological operations.** We create an elliptical shaped kernel then perform morph close to fill in the contours
- **Isolate area of interest.** We find contours and filter using contour approximation + contour area. Once we isolate the contour, find a minimum enclosing circle to obtain a perfect circle then draw this onto a blank mask. The idea to obtain a perfect circle is from [how to modify a mask to make a perfect circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59329583/how-to-modify-a-mask-to-make-it-perfect-circle)
- **Isolate ROI.** We find the bounding rectangle ROI on the mask then crop using Numpy slicing
- **Bitwise-and to obtain result.** Finally we bitwise-and the two extracted ROIs

---

Here's a visualization of each step:

Input image

[image]

Binary image

[image]

Morph close

[image]

Isolated area of interest highlighted in green and filled contour drawn onto a blank mask

[image]
[image]

Isolated ROIs

[image]
[image]

Bitwise-and for result (two versions, one with black background and one with white background, depending on what you want)

[image]
[image]

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, create blank mask, grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
original = image.copy()
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Morph close
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=5)

# Find contours and filter using contour area + contour approximation
# Determine perfect circle contour then draw onto blank mask
cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * peri, True)
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if len(approx) > 4 and area > 10000 and area < 500000:
        ((x, y), r) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        cv2.circle(mask, (int(x), int(y)), int(r), (255, 255, 255), -1)
        cv2.circle(image, (int(x), int(y)), int(r), (36, 255, 12), 3)

# Extract ROI
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(mask)
mask_ROI = mask[y:y+h, x:x+w]
image_ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]

# Bitwise-and for result
result = cv2.bitwise_and(image_ROI, image_ROI, mask=mask_ROI)
result[mask_ROI==0] = (255,255,255) # Color background white

cv2.imwrite('close.png', close)
cv2.imwrite('thresh.png', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('image.png', image)
cv2.imwrite('mask.png', mask)
cv2.imwrite('result.png', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**Note:** Another approach to determine the circular region of interest is to use Hough Circle Transform already implemented as [`cv2.HoughCircles()`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html) but there are many parameters so it may not be the most practical method.

Comment: I have an issue, that when I've tried the code with the same image, I end up with a mask completely black and no segmentation. I've seen that the issue appear in the for statement, do I have to change the parameters in peri, approx and area? Also if I have more images of samples, is this going to function for most of them ? or will I have to tune the code for each image. Thanks, don't want to bother, but I wanted to understand how to code works and then it didn't work.

Comment: which version of opencv have you used? I have 3.4.6

Comment: I'm using `python 3.7.4`, `numpy==1.14.5`, `opencv-python==4.1.0.25`. You may need to change the lower/upper area bounds, although it should work for most of your images